# Undefined index: custom_post_template_present

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm using a plugin for custom posts in my theme, the plugin is called "[Custom Post Templates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/)" i need to create custom posts.
At the moment i'm using the custom post template tv, but in the admin post editor i keep getting this error:

> NOTICE: C:\xampp\htdocs\clean\wp-content\plugins\custom-post-template\custom-post-templates.php:112 - Undefined index: custom_post_template_present
> get_default_post_to_edit, wp_insert_post, do_action('save_post'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, CustomPostTemplates->save_post

This

This is the part of the code where the error should be, I just can't figure out how to fix.

```
    public function save_post( $post_ID )
{
    $action_needed = (bool) @ $_POST[ 'custom_post_template_present' ];
    if ( ! $action_needed ) return;

    $this->post_ID = $post_ID;

    $template = (string) @ $_POST[ 'custom_post_template' ];
    $this->set_custom_post_template( $template );
}
```

Comment: You should contact the author and tell them to fix the issue - they should use something like `if ( empty( $_POST['custom_post_template_present'] ) ) { return; }` at the top in the function, instead of using the error control operator (`@`).

Comment: Thanks it works! The error has disappeared!